# How to organize list of string file names into a readable form?

Tags: python

Im making a script to anaylze file size changes over time and at the end I have a file that looks like this

```
{ 
  "path/to/file" : 10, 
  "second/path" : 20,
  "path/to/file/spefici" : 10, 
  "second/path/to/" : 20,
  "path/to/file/spefici/file.txt" : 10 
  "second/path/to/file.txt" : 20
}
```

But thats pretty hard to read and figure out what files change and what directories changed the most. How can I organize this dict so it looks more like this

```
{ 
  "path/to/file" : 10, 
  "path/to/file/specific" : 10, 
  "path/to/file/specific/file.txt" : 10 
  "second/path" : 20,
  "second/path/to/" : 20,
  "second/path/to/file.txt" : 20
}
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: If you are looking to store the output as a JSON, then you will need to modify the format to encode an ordering among the elements. Even if you can write to the file  in order, the JSON spec does not require that keys be kept in order, and so it is not guaranteed that parsing your JSON file would yield an object with the same order. You can either move away from JSON, or change the JSON structure (say have a list of dicts, each dict like `{"filename": "path/to/file", "filesize": 10}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = { 
  "path/to/file" : 10, 
  "second/path" : 20,
  "path/to/file/spefici" : 10, 
  "second/path/to/" : 20,
  "path/to/file/spefici/file.txt" : 10,
  "second/path/to/file.txt" : 20
}

sorted_data = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items())}

print(sorted_data)
```

Using dictionary comprehension it will print:

```
{
  'path/to/file': 10,
  'path/to/file/spefici': 10,
  'path/to/file/spefici/file.txt': 10,
  'second/path': 20,
  'second/path/to/': 20,
  'second/path/to/file.txt': 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a dictionary here since you don't sort json or dictionaries in general.

I would make it a list and sort that.

```
data = { 
  "path/to/file" : 10, 
  "second/path" : 20,
  "path/to/file/spefici" : 10, 
  "second/path/to/" : 20,
  "path/to/file/spefici/file.txt" : 10 
  "second/path/to/file.txt" : 20
}

filelist = sorted([ [x,y] for x,y in data.items() ]) # Alphabeticly from first field
#filelist = sorted([ [x,y] for x,y in data.items() ], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) # Filesize matters! Biggest first.

for file in filelist: # Present this however you want it
    print(file[0],file[1])
```

Commented# the sorting after filesize-line since you seem to want it alphabetically after /path/file.

Comment: Nah.  assuming these are paths, they are each unique in a file system and look ups by paths can be expected to be common.  Having it in a list loses the inherent uniqueness and lookups become costly with large datasets.   Lucian’s answer shows theres no inherent problem with sorting although it might be costly to build the whole list to sort in ram.